# How to put block comments in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

I have code here

```
proc checkPrime {no} { 
    set i 1 
    set count 0 
    while {$i < $no} { 
        if {{$no%$i} eq 0} {
            incr count 
        } 
        if {$count eq 2} { 
            puts "the number is prime number" 
            return 
        }
        incr i 
    } 
}
```

I want to put the whole procedure into a single comment, I don't want to have to put `#` before *each* line.

Is there any possibility to comment multiple lines in Tcl, as there is in Java using `/* .. */`?

I also want some of the text will be put into a single comment

Comment: A couple of errors in your code: use `eq` for string equality, `==` for numeric equality; `if {{$no%$i} eq 0}` should be `if {($no%$i) == 0}`

Comment: Another implementation for checking if a number is prime is at rosettacode.org: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division#Tcl

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apart from the `if {0} ..` which is idiomatic (and one that most tcl programmers recognize) you can also use any other construct and stuff the things you want commented out in brace quotes. The real mechanism preventing execution here is that things inside brace quotes don't get substituted.

Here are some of my favourites. I like them because they are self-documenting:

```
set COMMENTED_OUT {

    commented out stuff

}
```

and

```
proc COMMENTED_OUT {} {

    commented out stuff...

}
```

I tend to prefer the `proc` because the block of commented out text is really a block of code.

Note that tcl does not compile proc bodies until first execution so commenting out using a `proc` is as cheap as `set` and `if {0} ...`

Comment: of course, this won't work if the stuff you are commenting out is buggy and has unbalanced braces.

Answer (score 13):

Use something along these lines:

```
if { 0 } {
    a section
    of
    "commented" code
}
```

Comment: To be clear, Tcl does not parse the body *at all* in the case where it works out that it can never be executed (other than to check for curly brace balancing).

Comment: it needs to be mentioned that the 'if 0' trick won't work if the lines of code to be blocked out have unbalanced braces.

Comment: This answer needs trimming, as the question was updated long ago with the requested information (block of code and doesn't want to use `#`). I attempted to [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28108927), but it was (unfortunately) rejected.